# Azure Data Factory route to external SFTP without SHIR

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network

ADF with AIR connected to external SFTP server to grab file. This SFTP have firewall that have to whitelist IP address where connection come from. Trafix should be routed via Managed NET private endpoint and then some how to NAT gateway and public IP.

Is it possible to implement such thing ?

We want to avoid using any IaaS/VMs.

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you surely can implement such thing in your Azure environment considering that the SFTP server from which you have to grab a file is also hosted in Azure protected by an Azure firewall or even if it is not and if the SFTP server is hosted in on-premises protected by a hardware firewall, then also the setup for implementing this is quite possible.

For the above purpose, you will have to **deploy a private link service and a load balancer with public IP address enabled in your tenant**. Also, ensure that the **load balancer is hosted in a virtual network subnet** created in the **same region and resource group where Azure Data Factory with Azure Integrated runtime is deployed**. Since you have already deployed the ADF with AIR in the managed virtual network with private endpoints, it is possible for this **managed private endpoint in an approved state to send traffic** to a given private link resource.

•   **Once you create a private endpoint connection, it is in a ‘Pending’ state unless approved by the resource owner**. If the owner approves the connection, a private link is established. Otherwise, the private link won't be established. In either case, the managed private endpoint will be updated with the status of the connection. Once, the private endpoint is setup, then you can **setup the load balancer with the SFTP server’s public IP address as the backend and the private endpoint of the ADF with AIR as the frontend** for you to fetch the file from the SFTP server and initiate the connection from the ADF. Kindly refer to the below reference diagram and documentation link given for more information in this regard as to how to implement the said setup using the above stated Azure resources.

[image: ADF Architecture]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server

In the above link, you have to connect to an on-premises SQL server instead of a SFTP server and the ADF managed private endpoint is shown connecting to another allowed Azure service resources for which instead, in your case, you can directly connect it to **the Private Link service deployed** in as stated earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but not sure it will work. May be I was not clear in question ¨external SFTP server¨ means not-Azure and managed not by us. It is some server in internet. This approach with custom azure private link requires load balancer with back-end pool of VMs machines. I want to avoid any VMs in my VNETs. Currently I'm try ing to figure out how to run SHIR in windows container and then publish it on AKS.

Comment: I understood but if you visualize and go through the documentation correctly, and consider using the Azure private link service with the managed private endpoint, then it is possible to direct the traffic from the SFTP server to the ADF through the private endpoint itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found two options to do this:

1. Run SHIR at VMSS with custom extention installation.
2. Run SHIR at Windows Container at AKS. However AKS use VMSS behind, so VMSS looks more simple for some cases.

My goal was avoid using IaaS services to connect to external (non-Azure) SFTP server.

[image: possible options]

Comment: Alezis I had similar requirement and went with a hybrid architecture vs your pure cloud version.  I rely on on-premises SHIR nodes instead of your VMSS.  Why I did it that way is mostly historical ( originally we had security requirement restricting sensitive file-transfers to IPsec tunnel which we'd already built on-premises ) but the lesson learned is that SHIR SFTP is extremely slow compared with other SFTP clients such as FileZilla , WinSCP, etc. I'm interested what kind of file-transfer speeds you're experiencing and is it sufficient for your SLAs ?

Comment: Alezis also you mention `I want to avoid any VMs in my VNETs.` but then your architecture uses VMSS.

Comment: @BaltoStar, avoid VMs was security req acording to cloud policy of org. No IaaS. VMSS is allowed - it is PaaS